# jQuery checkboxes manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, how can I:

1. Have all checkboxes on a page turned checked `on` or `off`?
2. Loop through all the checkboxes on the page which are selected. I.e something like this

   ```
   $(sel-cboxes).each(myFunction);
   ```

So `myFunction` would be called on each selected checkbox.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1:
To check all checkboxes

```
$("input:checkbox").attr('checked', true);
```

To uncheck all

```
$("input:checkbox").attr('checked', false);
```

2:

```
$("input:checkbox:checked").each(myFunction);
```

Comment: yes, however this is discouraged because it is slow.
http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/checkbox

Answer (score 1):

> 1- Have all checkboxes on a page
>   turned checked on or off?
>   Edited:  (correction)

```
$(':checkbox').attr('checked',true);
```

> 2- Loop through all the checkboxes on
>   the page which are selected. I.e
>   something like this

```
$(':checkbox :checked').each(function() {

});
```

Comment: $(":checkbox").atrr is not a function
 $(":checkbox").atrr("checked",this.checked);

Answer (score 1):

This [jQuery Selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) will find all checkboxes that have been checked. and `this` inside the each function will be assigned to this individual checkbox.

```
$(":checkbox:checked").each(function(){
  doSomething(this);
})
```

If you want to turn all checkboxes `on` then use this:

```
$(":checkbox").attr("checked","checked")
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("input:checked")`

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/checked

Answer (score 0):

1: Set the all to be of the same class and then

```
$(.classname).attr('checked', true);
```